# Leaflet tiles are not loading for multiple Bootstrap tabs

Tags: leaflet, bootstrap-framework

I am making a web app for different areas using Leaflet library. I have different Bootstrap tabs, each tab opens a new map of a new area.

The problem I am facing is that the tiles on the first tab load but the tiles on the second tab do not. Where am I wrong?

This is how I am loading my maps for now...

```
/* MAP LAYERS */
var map = L.map('mapid',{
        zoomControl: true,
}).setView([24.2, 67.8], 9);

/* LOADING AND ADDING BASE MAPS */
var baseMap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);

/* MAP LAYERS */
var map1 = L.map('map_id',{
        zoomControl: true,
}).setView([22.2, 63.8], 9);

/* LOADING AND ADDING BASE MAPS */
var baseMap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map1);
```

My tabs:

```
<div  id = "locations">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#tabA" data-toggle="pill" role="tab">I</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#tabB" data-toggle="pill">J</a>
                    </li> 

                </ul> 
            </div> <!-- End Tabs -->
```

The tab linkage:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tabA" role="tabpanel"> <!-- First Tab -->
<div class="col-6" id = 'map_grid'> <!-- Maps -->
                                <div id ="mapid"> </div> <!-- Div for the Maps -->
                            </div> 
   </div>


<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabB" role="tabpanel"> <!-- Second Tab -->
<div class="col-6" id = 'map_grid'> <!-- Maps -->
                                <div id ="map_id"> </div> <!-- Div for the Maps -->
                            </div> <!-- End Maps -->
</div>
```

Comment: Map loads in DOM `<div>` element with `id` that is specified in the map initialization call. You have only `<div>` with `id='map_id'` for `map1`, but no `<div>` with `id='mapid'` for `map`.

Comment: I do. I just didn't post those lines... let me edit it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Leaflet map is displayed in it's `<div>` element, map's size is calculated on the basis of the `<div>` element size at the moment the map is added. If element is hidden, as it is the case of Boostrap tab above, `<div>` element has no size and consequently map has no size when tab is displayed.

Leaflet map has `invalidateSize()` method just for such cases. When this method is called, map's size is adjusted to the current size of it's `<div>` element.

All that is needed then is to catch the moment (event), when tab (HTML element) is displayed. One of the possible ways is to use `MutationObserver` DOM object to catch style changes in HTML element that holds the map.

Below is quick simple example of that can be done.

CSS

```
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .container-size {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .tab-size {
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
  }
  .map-size {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="container container-size">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  </ul>  
  <div class="tab-content tab-size">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active map-size">
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade map-size">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
  var map1 = L.map('home').setView([60, 30], 9);

  L.tileLayer('http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map &copy; OpenStreetMap'
  }).addTo(map1);

  var map2 = L.map('menu1').setView([60, 30], 9);

  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a> contributors',
  }).addTo(map2);

  var homeTab = document.getElementById('home');
  var observer1 = new MutationObserver(function(){
    if(homeTab.style.display != 'none'){
      map1.invalidateSize();
    }
  });
  observer1.observe(homeTab, {attributes: true});  

  var menu1Tab = document.getElementById('home');
  var observer2 = new MutationObserver(function(){
    if(menu1Tab.style.display != 'none'){
      map2.invalidateSize();
    }
  });
  observer2.observe(menu1Tab, {attributes: true});  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't aware of the MutationObserver. That sorted my problem.